# Very cheap device with UART interface

Tags: uart

I need to do some experimenting of UART,

I need a very cheap device that I could use to send/read from.

Please what could I use?

Something very cheap to buy

or

possibility something that I already have and I do not know supports UART.

Thanks

LISA

Comment: UART is an interface or just a piece of hardware. Look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver/transmitter. or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232. I think you need a device with a UART interface. You'd better  Google it first before asking here, that maybe more quicker.

Comment: @diverger sorry diverger, you're very right, I'll edit my question, if you think that is acceptable.

Comment: How can we know which 'somethings' you have that might contain a UART without you knowing it??? Most small micro-controllers contain a UART, but you'll need to program them to make any use of it. Stand-alone UART chips did exist(http://retired.beyondlogic.org/serial/serial1.htm#44), but they are now collectors items.

Comment: @diverger thanks diverger, I have a old laptop indeed, that might serve the purpose of getting/sending readings from/to the Android device. Thanks a lot for the other suggestions!! :-)

Comment: Any "Arduino" device has UART functionality. These are easy to learn and it is easy to set up the UART function. Prices vary depending on where you are but Chinese made versions of the physically smaller Arduinos can be bought in the $5-$10 range or local equivalent. (I get them in 10's from Chin for about $3 each!.) | Arduinos will "talk" to PCs via the USB bus, allowing a  PC to be used to set them up. | Arduino's originated in Italy but cheaper versions are made elsewhere. The products are open source so "clones" are legitimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few years ago, every PC is equipped with a RS232 interface, this is what you find, but nowadays more PCs abandon this interface, particularly true for notebooks. If you already have such a PC with RS232 port, you needn't to find another. But, your other question mentioned you need Android system, i don't know if Android can be installed on PC. If you haven't such a PC, you can find another board, with a MCU on it (almost any MCU nowadays support USART interface), and can run Android. If you insist on using a PC without RS232 port, you can buy a USB-to-RS232 translator, and plug it on your PC's USB port, it will work too.

And for your STM32 project, you do need a board with a STM32 MCU, and export the needed USART pins.